# How can I copy from in plpgsql function with input parameter filepath

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to read file temp table in a function, like below.

```
create or replace function test(filepath text)
returns void
as
$$
declare
begin

copy sometable from filepath;

end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

I can do than with execute.

```
execute format('
    copy sometable from %L with csv;
',filepath);
```